# How to format my output in text box same as inside the txt file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net. Below is my code on read a txt file and my txt file is quite large. I successfully read and display my Test.txt in txt2.Text, I want my output inside the Test.txt same line by line to be display inside the txt2.Text, I have set up my txt2.Text as multiple line. So when i enlarge my txt2.Text, my output will be the same as inside the Test.txt file. how do i used VbCrLf inside my code?

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Test.txt"
Dim Line As String = ""
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(filename)
   Line = sr.ReadLine
        Do
            If Line = "*" Then
                Line = sr.ReadLine
                Do
                    sb.Append(Line)     
                    Line = sr.ReadLine
                Loop Until Line = "**"
            End If
            Line = sr.ReadLine
        Loop Until Line = ""
    End Using
    txt2.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: What does that code do with `*` and `**`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop remove the CarriageReturn and LineFeed characters from the input line.
You could readd them changing this line

```
sb.Append(Line)
```

to

```
sb.AppendLine(Line)
```

But you will find soon that you have a bigger problem.
Inside the loop you execute various ReadLine without checking if you have really another line available to read. I don't know the structure of your file, but some kind of error checking is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

With a text file like this:

```
testdata10
*
testdata1
    testdata2
        testdata3
testdata4
testdata5
**
testdata11
```

Assuming that there are no more `*` before the `**` is reached, this code will add the appropriate lines to the textbox as is:

```
    Using sr As New IO.StreamReader("textfile1.dat")
        Dim line As String = ""
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            line = sr.ReadLine
            If line = "*" Then
                Do
                    TextBox1.AppendText(sr.ReadLine & vbNewLine)
                Loop Until sr.Peek = Asc("*"c)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```